# Error #1064 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=58' at line 11

This is my query :

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_cart` (
`ct_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`pd_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`ct_qty` mediumint( 8 ) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
`ct_session_id` char( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
`ct_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY ( `ct_id` ) ,
KEY `pd_id` ( `pd_id` ) ,
KEY `ct_session_id` ( `ct_session_id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =58;
```

Help Me What the problem is ...

Answer (score 26):

The keyword `TYPE` is removed since MySQL 5.1, use

```
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =58;
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_cart` (
`ct_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`pd_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`ct_qty` mediumint( 8 ) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
`ct_session_id` char( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
`ct_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY ( `ct_id` ) ,
KEY `pd_id` ( `pd_id` ) ,
KEY `ct_session_id` ( `ct_session_id` )
) ENGINE  = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =58;
```

Comment: maybe a little explanation would have been useful...