# mySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax (ENGINE=MyISAM)

Tags: php, mysql

At the first time I got such error, I realize the problem was similar to this question > [Error #1064 in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680349/error-1064-in-mysql) So I changed the `TYPE=MyISAM` on my code to `ENGINE=MyISAM`.

But even after the changing, I encountered similar error. It says,

`mySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14),
                        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                    ) ENGINE=M' at line 7`.

I thought changing to `ENGINE=MyISAM` would fix the error, but it doesn't. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
  $queries[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$prefix}conversationlog (
                    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                    input text default '',
                    response text default '',
                    thatresponse text default '',
                    uid varchar(255) default NULL,
                    enteredtime timestamp(14),
                    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is at the `(14)`, not `ENGINE=MyISAM`. The `TIMESTAMP` type does not take a size; it's always timestamp-sized.

Comment: Err, just to make sure. So I should change the `enteredtime timestamp(14)` to `enteredtime timestamp`?

Comment: Correct. Incidentally, you should also be specifying all of these columns as `NOT NULL` if appropriate.

Comment: So it would be `enteredtime timestamp NOT NULL`?

Comment: Yes, and similarly for all your other columns. `NOT NULL` goes before the `DEFAULT`.