# data base table create my sql coding error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am create table on MySQL database but showing this error message how to find error in this coding  ?

```
CREATE TABLE  `pqdb_articles` (
 `article_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `article_title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `article_text` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `article_cat` MEDIUMINT( 9 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `article_meta_key` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `article_meta_desc` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `article_id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =50972;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 50972' at line 19

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680349/error-1064-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `mySQL` replaced `TYPE` with `ENGINE`. Try this

```
ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50972;
```

Your query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `pqdb_articles` (
`article_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`article_title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
`article_text` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
`article_cat` MEDIUMINT( 9 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`article_meta_key` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
`article_meta_desc` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50972;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have solved this very easily, :|

just change TYPE to ENGINE

```
ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =50972;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TYPE use **ENGINE** as TYPE is not used in latest MYSQL

```
ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =50972;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =50972;
```

instead of

```
 TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =50972;
```