# MYSQL ERROR when trying a dump

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to install an older version of Joomla 1.5 on my server, my host has worked with me to allow 1.5 to install without error, however one of the issues is i need to do a mysql dump of the database, when i attempt to dump the database into the website i get the following error.

Error SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_banner` ( `bid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `cid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', `type` varchar(90) NOT NULL default 'banner', `name` text NOT NULL, `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', `imptotal` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', `impmade` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', `clicks` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', `imageurl` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', `clickurl` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', `date` datetime default NULL, `showBanner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0', `checked_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0', `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `editor` varchar(150) default NULL, `custombannercode` text, `catid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `description` text NOT NULL, `sticky` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=6' at line 29
```

Can anyone help me so i may correctly import the data?

Thanks again stackers.

Comment: You left out the code for the most important parts after `default '0000-00-[...]` which is where the error(s) is/are.

Comment: Can you also advise the version of MySql you are using. Is there any chance it's not aware of myisam? MySql 3.23 only included ISAM type. From 4.1 myisam was default I think. (am I the only one who sees the humour in the question heading?)

Comment: Here's what I found so far: *"The keyword TYPE is removed since MySQL 5.1, use `) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =6;`"* from [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9680349/) on SO.

Comment: @ActionDan Nope, you're not the only one (lol)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MySQL version is new enough that it doesn't recognize the older "TYPE" keyword and is instead expecting "ENGINE". Try editing your SQL file and replacing TYPE with ENGINE in that line and see if it imports (or, at least, the error message changes). You can make that change in a text editor (which hopefully has good search-and-replace functionality to make it easy to find any other occurrences -- but don't just blindly replace them all in case your data contains the term).

As Action Dan requested, knowing the MySQL version would help. It's displayed on the main phpMyAdmin page.

Also, just a little note, "dump" is when you export from a database; as far as I know there's no analogous term for importing (but you don't dump in to a database, only out).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code the mistake you have done is you have defined default value 0 in like this '0'

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_banner`(
`bid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
`cid` int(11) NOT NULL default 0, 
 `type` varchar(90) NOT NULL default 0, `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL , 
 `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 0, `imptotal` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
 `impmade` int(11) NOT NULL default 0, `clicks` int(11) NOT NULL default 0, 
 `imageurl` varchar(100) NOT NULL default 0, `clickurl` varchar(200) NOT NULL default 0, `date` datetime default NULL, `showBanner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default 0, 
 `checked_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default 0, `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `editor` varchar(150) default NULL, `custombannercode` varchar(255), `catid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, `description` text NOT NULL, `sticky` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL default 0, `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```