# While importing Database file in myPHP Admin I'm getting error CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wpcp_2_aiowps_event

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, datetime

While importing a Database file in myPHP Admin I'm getting the following error:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wpcp_2_aiowps_events` (   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `event_type` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,   `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,   `event_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',   `ip_or_host` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `referer_info` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `country_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `event_data` longtext,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1  MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 13

How can I solve this and import the data successfully without any errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680349/error-1064-in-mysql

Comment: that didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

> Note
>       The older TYPE option was synonymous with ENGINE. TYPE was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert existing applications that rely on TYPE to use ENGINE instead.

So you should use

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wpcp_2_aiowps_events ( id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, event_type varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', username varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL, user_id bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, event_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ip_or_host varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, referer_info varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, country_code varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, event_data longtext, PRIMARY KEY (id) )ENGINE = MyISAM ;
```

Comment: I still didn't understood.

Comment: Actually that is the mysql version issue, i used the same query in my db and table gets created successfully

Comment: I did those changes but now i am getting "Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

    Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "phpMyAdmin" at position 0)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "SQL" at position 11)

SQL query:

phpMyAdmin SQL Dump SET time_zone = "+00:00"

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump

SET time_zone = "+00:00"' at line 1"

Comment: what is this `+` inside the query  time_zone = "+00:00"'

Comment: it is like this in file "-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Jun 06, 2017 at 01:57 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 5.6.20

SET time_zone = "+00:00";


"